# Get Externally accessible IP address of Pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I need to create two instances using the same Ubuntu Image in Kubernetes. Each instance used two ports i.e. 8080 and 9090. How can I access these two ports externally? Can we use the IP address of the worker in this case?

Comment: "*Can we use the IP address of the worker in this case?*" - What worker? --- By default, pods only have internal IPs. If we want to expose a (group of) pod(s) accessible outside the cluster, we use an ingress or the deployment. Details can be found [here (ingress, `matthewpalmer.net/`)](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html) and [here (deployment, `medium.com`)](https://medium.com/swlh/kubernetes-external-ip-service-type-5e5e9ad62fcd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access your Ubuntu instances from outside the k8s cluster you should place pods behind the service.

You can access services through public IPs:

- create `Service` of type `NodePort`-  the `service` will be available on `<NodeIp>:<NodePort>`
- create `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` - if you are running your workload in the cloud creating service of type `LoadBalancer` will automatically deploy LoadBalancer for you.

Alternatively you can deploy `Ingress` to expose your `Service`. You would also need Ingress Controller.

Useful links:

- [GCP example](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps)
- [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/)
- [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)
- [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)